# Problem with querying an XML column with namespaces in SQL

Tags: sql-server

I need to get data from an XML:

```
DECLARE @input XML= 
'<Data xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
  <Data xmlns="http://test.com/xmlschema/Data_Schema.xsd">
    <Person defID="414123">
      <GlobalID Type="People" Code="112233" />
      <FirstName>John</FirstName>
      <LastName>Smith</LastName>
      <Email>john.smith@testcompany.com</Email>
      <Department>Sales</Department>
      <CountryCode>US</CountryCode>
      <CompanyName>Test Company</CompanyName>
    </Person>
  </Data>
</Data>';
```

I can't do anything about the XML structure, this is what I've tried already:

```
WITH XMLNAMESPACES('http://test.com/xmlschema/Data_Schema.xsd' AS x1)
   SELECT [Email] = PersonLevel.value('(Email)[1]', 'nvarchar(64)'), 
        [FirstName] = PersonLevel.value('(FirstName)[1]', 'nvarchar(64)'), 
        [LastName] = PersonLevel.value('(LastName)[1]', 'nvarchar(64)'), 
        [Department] = PersonLevel.value('(Department)[1]', 'nvarchar(64)'), 
        [CountryCode] = PersonLevel.value('(CountryCode)[1]', 'nvarchar(64)'), 
        [CompanyName] = PersonLevel.value('(CompanyName)[1]', 'nvarchar(64)')
 FROM @Input.nodes('/Data/x1:Data/x1:Person') AS XT1(PersonLevel);
```

My query results as NULL values, what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to include the namespace in your `value` expression:

```
WITH XMLNAMESPACES ('http://test.com/xmlschema/Data_Schema.xsd' AS x1)
SELECT PersonLevel.value('(x1:Email)[1]', 'nvarchar(64)') AS [Email],
       PersonLevel.value('(x1:FirstName)[1]', 'nvarchar(64)') AS [FirstName],
       PersonLevel.value('(x1:LastName)[1]', 'nvarchar(64)') AS [LastName],
       PersonLevel.value('(x1:Department)[1]', 'nvarchar(64)') AS [Department],
       PersonLevel.value('(x1:CountryCode)[1]', 'nvarchar(64)') AS [CountryCode],
       PersonLevel.value('(x1:CompanyName)[1]', 'nvarchar(64)') AS [CompanyName]
FROM @input.nodes('/Data/x1:Data/x1:Person') AS XT1(PersonLevel);
```

On a different note, do you really need everything to be an `nvarchar(64)`? I'd suggest that 64 characters may well not be enough for an email address (I've seen some really silly ones at times when businesses have long domain names, with sub domains, and full name addresses), however, 64 unicode characters is 62 characters for a country code (which is made up of 2 ASCII characters). You probably want to reconsider your datatypes here.

Comment: Thank you! Just what I was llooking for. I will reconsider the datatypes, just added something there quickly